# Child Routes not being hit

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an issue with my routes, whereby my children are never being hit..
take for example the following url routes array:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/apps', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'auth', component: AuthenticationComponent },
  { path: 'apps', component: ApplicationbrowserComponent},
  { path: 'apps/:id', component: VersionbrowsingComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', component: AuthenticationComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},         
      {path: 'versions', component: AuthenticationComponent},
      {path: 'versions/:id', component: AuthenticationComponent}
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', component: PagenotfoundComponent}
];
```

the children of `apps/:id` never get hit, only the parent seems to. For example if i was to type this into the url:

`mysite/app/myapp` I will (as expected) hit the 'apps/:id' route.

But if I put:

`mysite/app/myapp/versions`

I never reach the children, it ends up in the `apps/:id` route (the versionbrowsingcomponent loads).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you tried with `'/versions/:id'`?

Comment: No it complains if the path starts with a forward slash

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS 2

Comment: Hmmmm in this case you're not using right tags. I'll edit them.

Comment: Add versionbrowsing.component.html